# Arranging OS X application windows/workspace via presets

Tags: osx, window-manager, desktop-environment

Is there any software for OS X that can automatically arrange a workspace according to a preset?

By some sort of shortcut, I would like to launch applications and then place them in a certain way (position, size). It would be great if different arrangements are possible for multiple displays, if they are plugged in.

Budget: Anything from free to $15 USD.